# How to prevent ViewModel from being cleared when navigating away in BottomNavigationView using Navigation Component

Tags: android, viewmodel, bottomnavigationview, android-viewmodel

I'm having an issue saving the state of my fragment's UI and I can't seem to find any solutions regarding this problem when using a `BottomNavigationView`. Here's my current setup:

I have a `NavHostFragment` and a `BottomNavigationView` setup in **activity_main.xml**:

```xml
    <LinearLayout>
    ...
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/bottom_tab_nav" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_tab_menu"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/tab_btn_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/tab_btn_color"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/TabText"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/TabText"
        app:itemRippleColor="@color/background"/>
        ...
</LinearLayout>
```

I setup the `navController` in **MainActivity.kt** as follows:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    ...
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ...

        val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.bottom_nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        val bottomNavController =  navHostFragment.navController
        binding.bottomNavView.setupWithNavController(bottomNavController)

        ...
    }
```

In my navigation graph, I have two separate `Fragment` destinations:

1. **HomeFragment** which is the one I want to save.
2. **ProfileFragment** which is currently empty.

For the time being, **HomeFragment** contains all the UI logic that I want to migrate to **HomeViewModel** and save all my state in there. Here's my **HomeViewModel.kt** class:

```kotlin
class HomeViewModel: ViewModel() {
    init {
        Log.d(TAG, "HomeViewModel is Initialized.")
    }
    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        Log.d(TAG, "HomeViewModel is removed.")
    }
}
```

And in **HomeFragment.kt** I initialize my `ViewModel` as follows:

```kotlin
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    ...
    private lateinit var viewModel: HomeViewModel

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        ...

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[HomeViewModel::class.java]

        ...
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

#### My Problem:

Whenever I navigate to **ProfileFragment** I get nothing in the console, and then when I navigate back to **HomeFragment** again I get this output:

```
D/HomeViewModel: HomeViewModel is removed.
D/HomeViewModel: HomeViewModel is Initialized.
```

Which means my `HomeViewModel` is getting re-created.

**Note** that I'm not manually calling any `navigate` methods to navigate between the two fragments, navigation is done automatically by setting the **menu.xml** `item` ids to the same ids as the `HomeFragment` and `ProfileFragment` destinations.

#### Question:

How can I persist the state of `HomeViewModel` when navigating away from `HomeFragment` so that I could later on migrate all of my UI logic to it?

Also, any insights on how to manage the state of my `HomeFragment` using `ViewModel` would be apperciated.

Comment: What version of Navigation are you using? Only Navigation 2.4 and higher save the state of each tab

Comment: @ianhanniballake I just checked I'm using 2.3.5. So should I use 2.4.0 instead? And where can I find any documentation about saving the state of each tab in this new version? It seems super weird that they haven't made a way to solve such a common problem.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thank you, using the latest version `2.4.0-rc01` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you move away from a `Fragment`, Navigation component destroy its `View` later to be created from scratch whenever you navigate into it. In your `HomeFragment`'s `onCreateView`, you're creating a new instance of the `HomeViewModel` every time this happens. Instead, you can use a Fragment scoped ViewModel by using `by viewModels()` extension provided by `fragment-ktx` (see [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment))

```
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    ...
    private val viewModel by viewModels<HomeViewModel>()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        ...

        // Do not instantiate a ViewModel here

        ...
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same output, unfortunately :(

Comment: It seems it's a bug in all the Navigation versions prior to `2.3.5`, using the latest version `2.4.0-rc01` as @ianhanniballake suggested solved the issue